# LinkedIn profile info scraping using Selenium

Tags: python, selenium, selenium-webdriver, web-scraping

I am trying to scrape profiles from LinkedIn, I get profile URLs from the below code and want to pass it to driver.get(URL), however when I scrape URLs the format of URLs is different, e.g it is in [ ] brackets and I get this error

> selenium.common.exceptions.InvalidArgumentException: Message: invalid
> argument: 'url' must be a string

Could you please suggest how to get the proper format of URLs in the list **linklist = [ ]** so I can pass them to **driver.get(URL)**. Thanks!

```
options = Options()
options.add_argument("--start-maximized")
options.headless = True


url = "https://www.linkedin.com/login?fromSignIn=true&trk=guest_homepage-basic_nav-header-signin"
driver = webdriver.Chrome(path, options=options)

driver.get(url)
driver.find_element_by_id('username').send_keys('name')
driver.find_element_by_id('password').send_keys('password', Keys.ENTER)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_class_name('search-global-typeahead__input').send_keys('Marketing manager', Keys.ENTER)
driver.implicitly_wait(10)
driver.find_element_by_xpath('//button[text()="People"]').click()


x = 0
profile = []
linklist = []
condition = True
while condition:
    sleep(2)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1400);")
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    linkedin_members = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="entity-result__title"]')
    links = [linkedin_member.find_element_by_xpath('.//a[@class="app-aware-link"]').get_attribute('href') for linkedin_member in linkedin_members if "/in/" in linkedin_member.find_element_by_xpath('.//a[@class="app-aware-link"]').get_attribute('href')]

    x = x + 1
    linklist.append(link for link in links)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//button[@class='artdeco-pagination__button artdeco-pagination__button--next artdeco-button artdeco-button--muted artdeco-button--icon-right artdeco-button--1 artdeco-button--tertiary ember-view' and contains(.,'Next')]""").click()
    if x == 2:
        condition = False

profile = []

for l in tqdm(linklist):
    driver.get(l)
```

Comment: Linked in has an api available: https://www.linkedin.com/developers

Answer (score 0):

I used a *for* loop instad of the *while* loop you used, because there are no variable condition, you only want to do the loop twice.

Here's how you can do it:

```
linklist = []
for i in range(2):
    time.sleep(2)
    driver.execute_script("window.scrollTo(0, 1400);")
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    linkedin_members = driver.find_elements_by_xpath('//span[@class="entity-result__title"]')
    
    link = driver.find_element_by_class_name('app-aware-link').get_attribute('href')
    linklist.append(link)
    driver.implicitly_wait(10)
    driver.find_element_by_xpath("""//button[@class='artdeco-pagination__button artdeco-pagination__button--next artdeco-button artdeco-button--muted artdeco-button--icon-right artdeco-button--1 artdeco-button--tertiary ember-view' and contains(.,'Next')]""").click()

for url in linklist:
    driver.get(url)
```

I searched the class that contains the profile url and used "**.get_attribute('href')**" to extract the url.

Comment: I used While loop because I need to scrap all pages, I can change the value of x to 10 or any number to scrap different pages. I think if you use your code you can get duplicated profile URLs, correct me if I am mistaken